# ICO - in between a low gas transaction gets in, how?

Tags: ethereum

I am analyzing an ICO, successful transactions start here: https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x6267b5376c809445c9432bd9f14a3808b00eae2c&p=134

If you see the last column - most successful transactions paid a very high price (>0.1 ETH) but there are some in between which paid lil (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5b9145d94449fe01b7bcecee162e3adffd389997ba27a5c8724b632ca455b61c)

Question is -

1. How are these transactions able to get in between high price transactions? Is it just chance?
2. Is there some kind of strategy possible to make sure your transaction gets picked up - like if you are running a node?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the transactions for this contract to each other, yes, there is a big difference in tx costs. But, if you look specifically at the gas price, the buyers are paying a very big gas price across the spectrum. The high end transactions are paying 1k+ Gwei (some are even higher than 3k Gwei), but even the "cheapest" transactions you're looking at are still paying ~100 Gwei. Compared to other transactions on the blockchain, that's a high cost. The cost to have a transaction mined as fast as possible varies depending on congestion, but whenever I check [ethgasstation.info](http://ethgasstation.info), the high end gas prices are usually around 20-40 Gwei. As you can imagine, anything higher than that, miners are going to be eager to consume ASAP.

For your 2nd question, this is exactly the best strategy to have your transaction picked up the fastest. Pay a higher gas price.